# How to retrieve only one row with getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html

I'm pretty new to web dev and I have a hard time here to retrieve some info from the database... I'm doing this:

```
function readLine(i) {
    $.getJSON('../php/database.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            var output = "";
            var borderBegin = "<td style='border-left: 1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;";
            var borderEnd = "&nbsp;</td>";
            key = i;
            output = "<tr>" + borderBegin + key + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.name + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.firstname + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.tel + borderEnd + "</tr>";
            $("#resultsAdm").append(output);
        });
    });
}
```

I try to display only the row with the `i` index passed in argument to the function. I know the `$.each(..)` retrieves rows one by one (but displays all). I cannot figure how to do it with only one row... Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have control over the server code you should create an alternative action which only returns a specific row. Returning n number of rows ignoring 99% of returned data is a very expensive call to make each time.

Comment: I do have the control of the PHP-MySQL section. I tried from PHP to display that one line, but with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to display only the row with the i index passed in argument to
>   the function

If you only want to render the line from the index equal to `i` don't append unless you have a match.

At the start of each iteration, check if the `key` matches `i` and if not skip to the next item.

```
if(key != i){return true;}
```

Ones `key` matches `i`, process the lines, append it and then break out of the `.each` loop using `return false`.

I also commented out `key = i` as that doesn't seem right.

```
function readLine(i) {
    $.getJSON('../php/database.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            if(key != i){return true;}

            var output = "";
            var borderBegin = "<td style='border-left: 1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;'>&nbsp;";
            var borderEnd = "&nbsp;</td>";
            //key = i; Not sure what this is for?
            output = "<tr>" + borderBegin + key + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.name + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.firstname + borderEnd + borderBegin + value.tel + borderEnd + "</tr>";
            $("#resultsAdm").append(output);

            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Typo :) Should have have been `!=` , I hope the intend in the code was obvious and you tried `!=`

Comment: Yes, I figured! :)  Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

So your data contains multiple rows but you only want the first? Then `$.first()` should work.